# What material of core should I use for signal 1Mhz pulse transformer

Tags: transformer, pulse

I want to make 1Mhz pulse signal transformer, and I don't know what material should I choose. I found some epcos cores like N49 but it is for power transformers. Also I found some material with low THD but they are all for frequences under 1MHz

Comment: It depends what other specs you need and the net parasitic and load capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

The lower \$\mu_R\$ cores will support HF signals.  The overall specs of the load, volt-second, inductance, leakage inductance and parasitic capacitance with load capacitance will affect the signal integrity.

You might want to compare your overall specs with these HV gate drive pulse transformers.  They will also have the cores you need if you must DIY.

https://products.pulseelex.com/files/product_files/P883.pdf